# fHow to have separate login/logout screen with Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I have previously integrated with Okta and they have a sign in widget you can put into a page to log in with and call a controller to initiate the authentication/claims process. However, Azure AD does not seem to have anything like this so I wanted to use my razor page with our logo on it located in /pages/login/index to be the only folder for anonymous viewing. Basically I would like it to be the first screen anyone sees when they come to the site when not logged in and it will have a button which calls a controller post action to take you to Microsofts Azure AD Login screen. I have not seen any examples of this online so I am curious if this is even possible?

My current solution takes you straight to microsofts login:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using Project.Models;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2016.Drawing.ChartDrawing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

//authentication pipeline
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var RootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath;
var WebPath = builder.Environment.WebRootPath;
var fileDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(RootPath).Parent.ToString(), "armsfiles");
IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(fileDirectory);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);

//Not needed. We are not using this level of abstraction but may move towards it one day so possibly keep.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContext");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//We are making it so armsfiles are not accessible outside of arms so if we move to box or onedrive then the parameter may need to be removed.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = physicalProvider,
    RequestPath = "/files"
});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

app.Run();
```

I was thinking I could add this:

```
    // Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Login");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/files");
    });
```

But since there is no redirect for non logged in users that I can find I do not know if this option even makes a difference. So basically it is unclear how to setup the Program file to ensure not logged in users are redirected to this razor page (/login/index) and also what a controller for a sign in and sign out button would even look like! I am surprised I have struggled to find an example of this for ASP.NET Core 6.

**EDIT 11/22/2022
I have since got every component of my question solved except when a user goes to the site, if they are not authenticated I want to redirect them to "/login/" which hosts a page with a button that OnPost() does the following challenge:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    private string SignedOutRedirectUri;

    public IndexModel(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        SignedInRedirectUri = configuration["AzureAd:SignedInRedirectUri"];
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {

        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = SignedInRedirectUri },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    }
}
```

Is there a way to redirect users to a login page similar to how ASP.NET Core allows a redirect for their cookie options? ie,

```
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(cookieOptions =>
        {
            cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie";
            cookieOptions.LoginPath = "/Login/";
            cookieOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            cookieOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

Comment: For AAD-integrated projects created by default, doesn't the login page have buttons? This page should be tailored to your needs.

Comment: I think you are right but I added AAD to an existing app. My applications buttons also are written in vuejs so it can could call an api request or redirect to a logout razor page which would then call a OnGet() on load. Thats what I currently do but I do not know what the OnGet() should include since nothihng works :(

Comment: I have gotten everything to work except when a user is not logged in and going to the site for the first time it should redirect to /Login/ which is my welcome screen that has a button which OnPost() initiates the challenge. Any idea?

Comment: I tried to help you and post my solution in your newest case, could you kindly to check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `HomePageRouteModelConvention`.

   [image]

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;

   namespace WebApplication3
   {
    public class HomePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            if (model.RelativePath == "/Pages/Index.cshtml")
            {
                var currentHomePage = model.Selectors.Single(s => s.AttributeRouteModel.Template == string.Empty);
                model.Selectors.Remove(currentHomePage);
            }

            if (model.RelativePath == "/Pages/Login/Index.cshtml")
            {
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel()
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Template = string.Empty
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
   }
   ```
2. Refer my startup.cs file.

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
   using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
   using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

   namespace WebApplication3
   {
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.Add(new HomePageRouteModelConvention());
                    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Login");
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/files");
                });

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
   }
   ```
3. Others

   [image]

   [image]
4. Test Result:

   [image]

Comment: Okay so I have had time now to go through this. Thank you for putting this together. My only question is my goal is for the home page to be that /pages/login/index.cshtml page if not authenticated. If the user is authenticated it should be /pages/index.cshtml. So for that HomePageRouteModelConvention class you extend off of IPageRouteModelConvention, if you were to add User.IsAuthenticated() and used that to change the flow of this if the user is authenticated would that work? I never even knew this class existed.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment above?